# How can I condense a long list of items into categories for a repeated logit regression?

Tags: r, list, specifications, dummy-variable

I'm using a program called Apollo to make an ordered logit model. In this model, you have to specify a list of variables like this:

```
apollo_beta = c(
                b_var1_dum1 = 0,
                b_var1_dum2 = 0,
                b_var1_dum3 = 0,
                b_var2_dum1 = 0,
                b_var2_dum2 = 0,
                b_var3_dum1 = 0,
                b_var3_dum2 = 0,
                b_var3_dum3 = 0,
                b_var3_dum3 = 0)
```

I want to do two things:

Firstly, I want to be able to specify these beforehand:

```
specification1 = c(
                   b_var1_dum1 = 0,
                   b_var1_dum2 = 0,
                   b_var1_dum3 = 0,
                   b_var2_dum1 = 0,
                   b_var2_dum2 = 0,
                   b_var3_dum1 = 0,
                   b_var3_dum2 = 0,
                   b_var3_dum3 = 0,
                   b_var3_dum4 = 0)
```

And then be able to call it:

```
apollo_beta = specification1
```

Secondly, I want to be able to make categories:

```
var1 <- c(
          b_var1_dum1 = 0,
          b_var1_dum2 = 0,
          b_var1_dum3 = 0)
var2 <- c(
          b_var2_dum1 = 0,
          b_var2_dum2 = 0)
var3 <- c(
          b_var3_dum1 = 0,
          b_var3_dum2 = 0,
          b_var3_dum3 = 0,
          b_var3_dum4 = 0)
```

And then be able to use those in the specification:

```
specification1 = c(
                   var1,
                   var2,
                   var3)
```

And then:

```
apollo_beta = specification1
```

I know you might not have the best knowledge of the very niche programme Apollo. I am not quite sure if this is even possible, but since it would save me days (maybe weeks) of work, can anyone give me a hint on what I might be doing wrong? I worry I have a list within a list.
Since I have to make 60 specifications of the same model with different variations of 6 variables, it would be a lot of code and lot of work if I can't shorten it like this.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
var1_dum1 = c(0, 1, 0),
var1_dum2 = c(1, 0, 0),
var1_dum3 = c(0, 0, 1),
var2_dum1 = c(0, 1, 0),
var2_dum2 = c(1, 0, 0),
var3_dum1 = c(1, 1, 0),
var3_dum2 = c(1, 0, 0),
var3_dum3 = c(0, 1, 0),
var3_dum4 = c(0, 0, 1),
)
```

So there is a dataset with these variables. In apollo you specify "database = df" first, so it already refers to the variables.
In the list of apollo_beta, it doesn't refer to the variables directly, so technically you can call it what you want. I just want to call it the same as the variables as I will refer to them later.

My question is simple. Can I condense the long list to simply say "specification1". It's just a question of the r language. Whether the items of the list will function the same way as how it was originally written in code.

**In other words, would calling apollo_beta in the above three examples lead to the same result? If not, how do I change the code so that it does lead to the same?**

Comment: In what form do you have these variable names and values available? You show us what you want to get but not what initial data you have to work with.

Comment: Oh yes, they are variables part of a dataframe that takes value 0 or 1.

Comment: In Apollo, you first specify the dataframe you are working with.

Comment: Can you give an example? I am not sure what would be rows and columns in that data frame.

Comment: I added more explanation now.